# The best approcach for Multi-Site Codeigniter projects?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

**Here's what I want:**

I will have a main server, it will hold the client's package info, the themes they've ordered and a_ds they have attached from my marketplace.

I don't want their site to be a sub-domain, rather their own domain and it will be hosted by me in a shared environment.

Now, I want to set up my CI project in such a way, that these will happen. Each individual client will be given their own project space and database but I want their particular projects to derive their settings from my database/CI functions.

I know I wrote terribly, but even Google failed me on this. You guys are my last hope.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you intend to run these multitude of sites from one CodeIgniter source in your server, with  application configurations varying depending on which domain is accessed?

If that is the case, then here is an option available for you off the top of my head:

Organize the varying configurations in `application/config` like this:

```
application/
    config/
        domains/
            foo.com/
                database.php
                config.php
            bar.net/
                database.php
                config.php
            baz.org/
                database.php
                config.php
```

Each of these `application/config/domains/*/(database|config).php` files contain the configurations specific only for that particular domains (You have to generate these somehow).

Example:

```
  //In database.php files
  return array(
       'username' => 'client1',
       'password' => 'password!',
       'database' => 'client1_db'
  );

  //In config.php files
  return array(
       'base_url' => 'http://baz.org'
  );
```

Then its just a matter of including the right file depending on the domain used in the request:

In your `application/config/database.php`:

```
  $client_vars = include __DIR__ . '/domains/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/database.php';

  /* validate $client_vars to ensure that client is not overriding anything important. Throw an error to inform client. */
  $db['default'] = array_replace($db['default'], $client_vars);

  /* Rest of DB settings. */
```

In your `application/config/config.php`:

```
  $client_vars = include __DIR__ . '/domains/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/database.php';

  /* validate $client_vars to ensure that client is not overriding anything important. Throw an error to inform client */
  $config = array_replace($config, $client_vars);

  /* Rest of config settings */
```

This is a rough idea of a possible solution, though this is not very secure at all. Just two cents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain what security risks I would take by doing this? Much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to move these domain-specific configuration files away from your project source-tree itself, especially if you wish to provide access to these configuration files to the clients. 

Also the way CodeIgniter just provides you the `$config` and `$database` variables to modify directly is a security hole -- what if a client modify settings that should not be modified? (Will edit my answer for a solution.)

Another is that the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is not available in CLI. You have to find a way to get around that (Maybe capture a CLI argument and locate the appropriate config file).

Comment: Note that `array_replace` is only available on version 5.3 or higher. `array_merge` would be enough for your needs, most likely.